# How to get Map keys by values in Dart?

Tags: dictionary, dart, key

In Dart language how to get MAP keys by values?

I have a Map like;

```
{
  "01": "USD",
  "17": "GBP",
  "33": "EUR"
}
```

And I need to use values to get keys. How do I do that?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
var usdKey = curr.keys.firstWhere(
    (k) => curr[k] == 'USD', orElse: () => null);
```

Comment: Thanks Günter its working... By the way where I can get details information for this? So I can study to understand and I can use late in my advance Map project?

Comment: I don't think this is documented as a thing by itself. There is the `keys` property of `Map` and the `firstWhere` method of `Iterable` and the rest is using them together in a meaningful way. https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Map/keys.html, https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html

Answer (score 23):

If you will be doing this more than a few times on the same data, you should create an inverse map so that you can perform simple key lookup instead of repeated linear searches.  Here's an example of reversing a map (there may be easier ways to do this):

```
main() {
  var orig = {"01": "USD", "17": "GBP", "33": "EUR"};
  var reversed = Map.fromEntries(orig.entries.map((e) => MapEntry(e.value, e.key)));
  for (var kv in reversed.entries) {
    print(kv);
  }
}
```

Edit:  yes, reversing a map can simply be:

```
var reversed = orig.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
```

Tip of the hat to Joe Conway on gitter.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

There is another one method (similar to Günter Zöchbauer answer):

```
void main() {

  Map currencies = {
     "01": "USD",
     "17": "GBP",
     "33": "EUR"
  };

  MapEntry entry = currencies.entries.firstWhere((element) => element.value=='GBP', orElse: () => null);

  if(entry != null){
    print('key = ${entry.key}');
    print('value = ${entry.value}');
  }

}
```

In this code, you get MapEntry, which contains key and value, instead only key in a separate variable. It can be useful in some code.

Comment: This was useful since (element) contains both key & value and helped me in the test condition with both key & value, since I had same values but different keys but I required both entries. Since 'firstWhere' was ignoring the duplicate. Thanks

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. MapEntry really help to visualize the structure of data, which can be very useful for debugging and testing.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me! This answer should have more upvote!

Answer (score 6):

```
Map map = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'};

var key = map.keys.firstWhere((k) => map[k] == 'two', orElse: () => null);
print(key);
```

Comment: While this code may help with the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Comment: in my case worked: map.entries.firstWhere((element) => element.value == 'two', orElse: () => null).key;

Answer (score 3):

If someone still need a solution, I wrote a [simple library](https://pub.dev/packages/deep_collection) to deeply (search inside nested maps either) search by value inside `Map`. Usage is simple, because `deepSearchByValue()` is an extension method, so all you need to do is to import my library and call the method on your map:

```dart
import 'package:deep_collection/deep_collection.dart';


void main() {
  print({
    "01": "USD",
    "17": "GBP",
    "33": "EUR",
  }.deepSearchByValue((value) => value == 'USD'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :

```
var mapper = { 
              '01' : 'USD',
               '17' : 'GBP'     } 

for(var val in mapper.keys){

  switch(mapper[val]){

        case 'USD' : {
                             print('key for ${mapper[val]} is : ' '${val}');  
            }

          break;

        case 'GBP' : {
                             print('key for ${mapper[val]} is : ' '${val}');   
               } 

        }
          }
```

Comment: Not effective and reusable. You hardcode values in `switch`, which make it hard to maintain and refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Randal Schwartz's answer:

```
Map<T, R> invertMap<T, R>(Map<R, T> toInvert) =>
  Map.fromEntries(toInvert.entries.map((e) => MapEntry(e.value, e.key)));
```

Answer (score 1):

An *extension* of Randal Schwartz's answer.

```
extension InvertMap<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  Map<V, K> get inverse => Map.fromEntries(entries.map((e) => MapEntry(e.value, e.key)));
}
```

This provides us with a highly reusable solution:

```
var inverseMap = originalMap.inverse;
```